# Will value objects in a copy of a static ConcurrentHashMap reference the same value objects as the original?

Tags: java, static, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

I have a two part question.

I have:
    `private static ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Servers> servers= null;`
which I later populate.  In method `getAllServers`, I'm doing this:

```
public static synchronized ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Server> getAllServers() {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Server> toReturn = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    for(Integer i = 0; i < servers.size(); i ++ ) {
        Server s = servers.get(i);
        if(s.isAlive()) {
            s.incrementConns();
            toReturn.put(i, s);
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Q: Will modifications to `s` be reflected in `servers`?

Q: Will `toReturn` reference the same Server objects as in `servers`?  If so, would any class that creates and modifies `getAllServers`'s returned map be modifiying the same objects as `servers`?

**Update**: @chrylis: 
Which `Iterator` are you referring to?  Can you please explain why the for loop is a bad idea a bit more?  I do use this as well, in other areas:

```
Iterator itr = servers.entrySet().iterator();
            Map.Entry pair;
            while(itr.hasNext()) {
                pair = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
                Server s= (Server) pair.getValue();
                ...
```

But I don't see anything wrong since I know `servers` will contain Servers with `Integer` ids ranging from 0 onward. When I iterate over them in the for loop, the order is not a concern for me.

Comment: Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html) to start. `ConcurrentHashMap` isn't really important. You need to understand object references.

Comment: For starters, your loop is quite brittle; there's no guarantee that your keys are a sequential set of numbers, and if there were, a `List` would make more sense. Is there reason you're not iterating over `servers.entrySet()`? Also, you are talking about "value objects", but `s.incrementConns()` sounds like a mutator.

Comment: Yes, and Yes, and Yes

Comment: @chrylis: the key used for Server objects is an Integer parameter in the class, which is assigned to the objects at their construction in a static ServerCreator class.  Sequence doesn't matter, as long as the iteration goes through all the values of the map, which are Server objects.  Yes, `incrementConns()` is a mutator that modifies another parameter of the object - is using a mutator in the same loop a bad idea?

Comment: The iterator *won't* go through all of the values unless they are always, always, exactly 0 through the length of the map minus one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and yes.  It may not even be *possible* to copy `Server` objects, as far as this code is concerned.  This has nothing to do with `ConcurrentHashMap`, and everything to do with how references work in Java.

Answer (score 2):

1. `servers` only hold references to the `Server` objects: whatever modification you make to the underlying objects will be reflected in `servers` too.
2. [Java passes references by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference), so yes.

Note that if your code is not properly synchronized, you might see stale and/or inconsistent `Server` objects in your code, but that is a different issue.