# Are these two methods equivalent?

Tags: java, static, concurrenthashmap

This question is related to one I just asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492706/will-value-objects-in-a-copy-of-a-static-concurrenthashmap-reference-the-same-va).

Given`servers` is a `private static ConcurrentHashMap`, are the following two methods and the third approach all equivalent in that the `servers` map will reflect the change made by all three?

1.

```
public static synchronized int releaseConnection(Server s) {
    return servers.get(s.getId()).decrementConns();
}
```

2.

```
public static synchronized int releaseConnection(Server s) {
    return s.decrementConns();
}
```

3.  just call `decrementConns()` where its needed (in other classes)?

Comment: What if it isn't in the map?

Comment: Also, don't use `synchronized` methods; they don't provide appropriate levels of granularity.

Comment: If the instance in the map (given it is found there, of course, as SLaks pointed out!) and the instance given as an argument are the same, the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd way is best and should be sufficient.
All 3 will do the job but 1 and 2 are not needed as you are working with `ConcurrentHashMap`.